# Using a configuration list of JSON paths in a script to dynamically transform from one payload to another

Tags: python

I have an existing question which may have been initially too big so I am breaking it down into smaller questions so that I can piece it together. Related question is [Python JSON transformation from explicit to generic by configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073060/python-json-transformation-from-explicit-to-generic-by-configuration).

I want to be able to process some transformations using a configuration list which it would **try** each listed JSON path and where it can successfully create an object, it would append it to an array called `characteristics`.

INPUT DATA

This data is a single value from an explicit data payload which has over 2,500 values individually defined at schema level. It's nasty hence we want to transform it into a more data driven object which can be maintained through configuration. Unfortunately, we have no control over the input data, else we would ask for the data to arrive in the preferred generic state instead.

```
data = {
    "activities_acceptance" : {
        "contractors_sub_contractors" : {
            "contractors_subcontractors_engaged" : "yes"
        }
}
```

CONFIGURATION JSON

This configuration example is used to create an object with `category` and `type` and for this example, adds a single value. The `set_value` may be used to add more than one mapped value from the origin data.

```
config = {
    "processing_configuration" : [
        {
            "origin_path" : "activities_acceptance.contractors_sub_contractors",
            "set_category" : "business-activities",
            "set_type" : "contractors-sub-contractors-engaged",
            "set_value" : [
                {
                    "use_value" : "contractors_subcontractors_engaged",
                    "set_value" : "value"
                }
        ]
}
```

MANUAL METHOD in PYTHON

This script is currently working but requires me to create a repeat of this for every generic object I want to create. I need the configuration JSON to be looped through instead thus reducing script and allows the addition of new data to be configuration management.

```
# Create Business Characteristics

business_characteristics = {
"characteristics" : []
}

# Create Characteristics - Business - Liability

try:
    acc_liability = {
        "category" : "business-activities",
        "type" : "contractors-sub-contractors-engaged",
        "description" : "",
        "value" : "",
        "details" : ""
    }
    acc_liability['value'] = data['line_of_businesses'][0]['assets']['commercial_operations'][0]['liability_asset']['acceptance']['contractors_and_subcontractors']['contractors_and_subcontractors_engaged']
    business_characteristics['characteristics'].append(acc_liability)
except:
    acc_liability = {}
```

What I'm trying to set the path for `acc_liability['value'] using the configuration JSON like as shown below.

Note, I used a `.` separator for the entire path to avoid having to do all the `['']` throughout the whole configuration file so, not only do I need it to read from the configuration but also, for each path depth, wrap in a `['']`. If that complicates things from a script perspective, I'll just use the full path as I have entered in the manual version.

DYNAMIC VERSION - currently not working and need help on

```
# Create Business Characteristics

business_characteristics = {
"characteristics" : []
}

# Create Characteristics - Business - Liability

try:
    acc_liability = {
        "category" : "",
        "type" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "value" : "",
        "details" : ""
    }
    acc_liability['category'] = config['processing_configuration'][0]['set_category']
    acc_liability['type'] = config['processing_configuration'][0]['set_type']
    acc_liability['value'] = data config['processing_configuration'][0]['origin_path'] + config['set_value']`
    business_characteristics['characteristics'].append(acc_liability)
except:
    acc_liability = {}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
{
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "category": "business-activities",
      "type": "contractors-sub-scontractors-engaged",
      "description": "",
      "value": "YES",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should think about reworking your data-structure. This is unreadable

Comment: which one, the input or the output? I kept it down to the bare minimum as I could. The output is supposed to be generic and for each value it is assigned a category and type so you can carry any values from the horrible input (which has over 2,500 schema definitions) into a generic one which can be filtered and used consistently